# Getting yesterday - The method getDate() from the type Date is deprecated

Tags: java, date

I try to get the date of yesterday. So I write the next function:

```
public  String getYestrday() {
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date date = new Date();
    return dateFormat.format(date.getDate() - 1);
}
```

But it gives me the next warning:

```
The method getDate() from the type Date is deprecated
```

and it doesn't do it work.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The deprecation text hints to `Calendar` if you read it completely

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[**Date#getDate()**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) is a deprecated method after JDK 1.1. You should be using [**Calendar**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class instead to manipulate dates.

From [**API**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html):

> Prior to JDK 1.1, the class Date had two additional functions. It
>   allowed the interpretation of dates as year, month, day, hour, minute,
>   and second values. It also allowed the formatting and parsing of date
>   strings. Unfortunately, the API for these functions was not amenable
>   to internationalization. As of JDK 1.1, the Calendar class should be
>   used to convert between dates and time fields and the DateFormat class
>   should be used to format and parse date strings. The corresponding
>   methods in Date are deprecated.

It is also clearly documented in the API using [**Date#getDate()**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) to use `Calendar#get(Calendar.DATE);`

> Deprecated.  As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by
>   Calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
return dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
```

Comment: +1 for avoiding extra libraries for a small task. Either `Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH` or `Calendar.DATE` will do, they're synonyms.

Answer (score 1):

Use `java.util.Calendar` to do it. Or try [JODA](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class to do the same task:

```
Calendar c = new Calendar();
//c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
Date d = c.getTime();
```

Comment: java.util.Calendar's empty constructor is protected. Use Calendar.getInstance().getTime(); instead

Answer (score 0):

## Avoid java.util.Date & .Calendar

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14938297/642706) is correct. However, the java.util.Date and .Calendar classes are notoriously troublesome. Avoid them. Use either [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) or the new [java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) (in Java 8).

## Separate Date-Time Manipulation From Formatting

Also, the code in the question mixes date-time work with formatting. Separate those tasks to make your code clear and testing/debugging easier.

## Time Zone

Time zone is critical in date-time work. If you ignore the issue, the JVM's default time zone will be applied. A better practice is to always specify rather than rely on default. Even when you want the default, explicitly call [`getDefault`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html#getDefault%28%29).

The beginning of the day is defined by the time zone. A new day dawns earlier in Paris than in Montréal. So if by "yesterday" you mean the first moment of that day, then you should (a) specify a time zone, and (b) call [`withTimeAtStartOfDay`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withTimeAtStartOfDay%28%29).

## Joda-Time

Example code in Joda-Time 2.3.

```
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Paris" );
DateTime today = DateTime.now( timeZone );
```

Or convert from a java.util.Date object.

```
DateTime today = new DateTime( myJUDate, timeZone );
```

Subtract a day to get to yesterday (or day before).

```
DateTime yesterday = today.minusDays( 1 );
DateTime yesterdayStartOfDay = today.minusDays( 1 ).withTimeAtStartOfDay();
```

By default, Joda-Time and java.time parse/generate strings in [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

```
String output = yesterdayStartOfDay.toString(); // Uses ISO 8601 format by default.
```

Use a formatter for a full date as four digit year, two digit month of year, and two digit day of month (yyyy-MM-dd). Such a formatter is already defined in Joda-Time.

```
String outputDatePortion = ISODateFormat.date().print( yesterdayStartOfDay );
```

Answer (score 0):

Following works for me

```
int date = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```