# Subtract date to get yesterday date

Tags: java, date

I have these codes to get the date today in my server

```
 DefaultTableModel dnow = MyDB.DataTable("SELECT date_format(now(),'%m-%d-%Y')");
```

and these code for the formatting for the date.

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
```

now how can I get the date of yesterday?
should I just minus it with one?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if a date Object equals yesterday?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3006150/642706) and [Getting yesterday - The method getDate() from the type Date is deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14938253/642706).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative approach is to do the math in SQL.  The statement may vary depending on what database platform you're using.

```
DefaultTableModel dnow = 
  MyDB.DataTable("SELECT date_format(now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY,'%m-%d-%Y')");
```

Answer (score 1):

No, build a `Date` (or better yet use [joda](http://joda-time.sf.net)'s `DateTime` object) and then do your arithmetic. I will give you two solutions, one with Joda and the other without, starting with without:

```
Date d = format.parse(dnow.getDataVector().get(dnow.getTable().getSelectedRow()));
d.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
```

Now, using joda:

```
DateTime d = new DateTime(format.parse(dnow.getDataVector().get(dnow.getTable().getSelectedRow()))).minusDays(1);
```

Comment: dataVector has protected access in datatablemodel

Answer (score 0):

This should work perfect for you,

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance()
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
System.out.println("Yesterday's date = "+ cal.getTime());
```

This will simply subtract 1 day from the current calendar date, providing you yesterdays date

Comment: no.. sorry but i used  DefaultTableModel dnow = MyDB.DataTable("SELECT date_format(now(),'%m-%d-%Y')");

Comment: cause the user can change it to the date setting thats why Im using the server's time

Answer (score 0):

If you store your timestamps internally as POSIX times (milliseconds since MN Jan 1, 1970) then you can add or subtract a day to any time stamp as easily as:

```
Date today = new Date(); // today
Date tomorrow = new Date(today.getTime() + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)); // tomorrow
```

The huge bonus to POSIX time is that it is always in UTC.  UTC is a global, "fixed" point of reference. Then if you need to need to have this date displayed for the user in any time zone, in any daylight savings zone, for any place that is accounted for in the Olson Time Zone database, you can simply create a Calendar:

```
GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Chicago"));
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat();
sdf.setCalendar(gc);
sdf.applyPattern("MM-dd-yyyy");

// Now your formatter is set with the pattern and a time zone-aware Calendar. 
// The world is at your command

String myOutput = sdf.format(tomorrow);
```

I highly recommend dealing with timestamps internally in your data model in some form of UTC representation. Doing date arithmetic with POSIX time (or Julian Day Numbers, or Modified Julian Day Numbers) is easy peasy, and the Java date/time API has enough capability to deal with most local time conversions without much fuss from you.