# Getting hours,minutes, and seconds from Date?

Tags: java, swing, date, time

I want to get the current hour,minute, and second from the `Date` object.

This is my code:

```
Date date = new Date();
int hour = date.getHours();
```

But I get a kind of error, the `getHours()` part doesnt work. I get a "The method getHours() from the type Data is deprecated". What does that mean, and how do I get the hour,minutes, and seconds?

Comment: Deprecation is not an error, but a warning. While it isn't good practice to use a deprecated method, it still "should work", though bugs for it won't be fixed by the author, and it might disappear later.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/14938297/1848261

Comment: this is superseeded by java8: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25539891/how-to-get-the-current-hour-with-new-date-time-api-in-java-8

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Use [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);  
int hours = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
```

From `Date` [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getMinutes--):

> Deprecated. *As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by `Calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE)`.*
>
> Returns the number of minutes past the hour represented by this date, as interpreted in the local time zone. The value returned is between 0 and 59.

Comment: I looked for Java Native solution to LocalDateTime on Android.
You helped me find it. Kudos Dude!