# How to get the current hour with new Date-Time API in Java 8?

Tags: java, java-8, java-time

Before Java 8 the common method was the `Calendar` API:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
```

How can I get the current hour, but using the new [Date-Time API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html) provided in **Java 8**?

Comment: [`LocalTime#getHour`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#getHour--)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This all depends, but something like...

```
LocalTime now = LocalTime.now();
System.out.println(now.getHour());
```

Should work just fine...

Take a closer look at [`LocalTime#getHour`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#getHour--) for more details

Comment: What do you mean by `This all depends`?

Comment: @ScaryWombat From my perspective, there's no context, and I simply jumped in at `LocalTime`, there's also `Clock`/`Instant`, `LocalDateTime`, `OffsetDateTime` and `OffsetTime`...so, it "depends"