# compare two time in fragment is not working

Tags: android, time, push-notification, compare

here is what i do and its not working ... i get time from shared preference from timepicker this time is picked by user at runtime name as first time ... and in the fragment i need to compare system current time with first time to send notification . but if condition is not working during comparison. and when i remove if condition and then notification works good problem is in compare time . it do not show me any error.

public Long firstTimeinLong;

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")

@Nullable

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        getActivity().setTitle("Blood Pressure");

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blood_pressure, container, false);


    Date myDate = new Date(); // Default Value.

    Long dateTimeinLong = myDate.getTime();


    SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("MY_PREFS_BPTIME_CHECKS", MODE_PRIVATE);

    firstTimeinLong = prefs.getLong( "millis1",0 ); // firstTime1


    System.out.println("System Time : " + dateTimeinLong);
    System.out.println("First Time : " + firstTimeinLong);



    if (dateTimeinLong == firstTimeinLong.longValue()  )// i dont know why this is not working but i do not get any error
        {
            LGSnackbarManager.show(INFO, "first time is here in the loop");
            Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), NotificationBroadcastReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 12345678, notifyIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(getActivity().getApplicationContext().ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(),1000, pendingIntent);
        }

        return view;
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you have value in `SharedPreference` on the first time?
Show your `System.out.println` result please.

Comment: may this helps, https://stackoverflow.com/a/20542511/6016830

Comment: yes i need to get first time by user  this is the resuslt in system.out.println

Comment: I/System.out: System Time : 1531118700077                        and this is the first time I/System.out: First Time : 1531118806737 i want that when first time match with system time then condition work and notification sends

Comment: you probably can't catch a moment when it is equal up to a millisecond. Try to expand interval to a second for example

Comment: my first time is user pick the time from Time picker and i convert that time to Long like this if it is wrong then please correct me

Comment: Calendar timeStamp =  timePickerInputEditTextFirstTime.getTime(); 

        Date date = new Date( String.valueOf( timeStamp.getTime() ) );
        Date LongTime = timeStamp.getTime();
      final Long millis1 = LongTime.getTime();

Comment: Why are you expecting that the code inside if will be executed since you' re comparing a date/time from the past which you already stored in SharedPreferences with the current date/time?

Comment: then it means i dont need to compare first time with system time to send push notification ????

Comment: This comparison will never succeed. I don't understand exactly what you're trying to do

Comment: ok my main purpose is to send notification to user when the first time comes ..

Comment: Remove the if statement and keep the code that sends the notification

Comment: i am trying now and then tell you any thing that will happen

Comment: yes when i remove if condition then notification works perfect .... but how do i do that when firstTime comes like if ( firstTime) then sendpush notification this is what i want please help me

Comment: What do you mean when firstTime comes?

Comment: i get the first time from an activity using Time Picker edit text and this first time i convert it to long  like this final Long millis1 = LongTime.getTime(); then i save and send this time(first time ) from one activity to fragment activity and get that first time with the help of shared preference like editor.getLong and then i want to show the notification when the first time comes. this first is user pick the time using time picker

Comment: first time is a time picker edit text this is      final  String firsttime = timePickerInputEditTextFirstTime.getText().toString();

Answer (score 0):

thank you all of you respectful engineers i really like that you all respond to my problem quickly ...  i solved my problem with these four links this 4 links helped me in my case and i do not need to compare with the system current time.

4 -- [Best way to compare dates in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10774871/best-way-to-compare-dates-in-android)
3 -- [How to repeat notification daily on specific time in android through background service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23440251/how-to-repeat-notification-daily-on-specific-time-in-android-through-background)
2 -- [Getting hours,minutes, and seconds from Date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25474033/getting-hours-minutes-and-seconds-from-date)
1 -- [How to save and retrieve Date in SharedPreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12343014/how-to-save-and-retrieve-date-in-sharedpreferences#)

first i use

```
Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
```

and set the user difined time `prefs.getLong`  value in cal1 like this

```
cal1.setTimeInMillis(prefs.getLong(key"millis1", defValue 0));
```

and then i get the (saved time that i set to ) cal1 like this

```
Date firstTimeinLong = cal1.getTime();
```

and now i split my time like this

```
int minutes1 = cal1.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
int hour1 = cal1.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int second1 = cal1.get(Calendar.SECOND);
```

and the i use another calendar object for notification and set the MINUTE, HOUR_OF_DAY and SECOND like this

```
Calendar cal2forNotify = Calendar.getInstance();
cal2forNotify. calendarforNotification.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour1);
cal2forNotify.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minutes1);
cal2forNotify.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
```

and last change is in the alarmManger.setRepeating  line like this

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendarforNotification.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

here is the Code solution
[code is in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3cAm.png)